# How to delete client-details-list from my api view

Tags: api, listview, django-rest-framework

[image: Here is my client details list]

```
#API View
@api_view(['GET'])
def clientDetail(request,pk):
    details = ClientAPI.objects.get(id=pk)
    serializer = ClientSerializer(details,many=False)
    return Response(serializer.data)

#API List
@api_view(['GET'])
def clientDetailList(request):
    list = ClientAPI.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    serializer = ClientSerializer(list,many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Here is my api view code .Now how i add delete function to delete the client detail list.

I try to delete my client details list .Can you show me the function i add my views.py

Answer (score 0):

It just like detail:

```
from rest_framework import status


#API View
@api_view(['DELETE'])
def clientDelete(request,pk):
    client = ClientAPI.objects.get(id=pk)
    client.delete()  # or something your code.
    return Response({
        "message": "Client was deleted."
    },status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to delete this list item. I try your code but I couldn't delete this list
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

[
{
"id": 9,
"status": "True",
"inputvalues": "[10, 9, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]",
"timestamp": "2022-11-09T05:22:52.357502Z"
},
{
"id": 8,
"status": "True",
"inputvalues": "[99, 77, 69, 44, 10, 6, 5, 2, 1]",
"timestamp": "2022-11-08T11:45:53.320006Z"
},
{
"id": 7,
"status": "False",
"inputvalues": "[19, 14, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]",
"timestamp": "2022-11-08T11:24:36.862230Z"
},
{
"id": 6,
"status": "True",
"inputvalues": "[11, 10, 9, 7, 6, 5, 1]",
"timestamp": "2022-11-08T11:21:14.914640Z"
},
{
"id": 5,
"status": "False",
"inputvalues": "[133131]",
"timestamp": "2021-09-24T17:11:08.217355Z"
},
{
"id": 4,
"status": "False",
"inputvalues": "[133131]",
"timestamp": "2021-09-24T17:10:20.041078Z"
},
{
"id": 3,
"status": "False",
"inputvalues": "[8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 1]",
"timestamp": "2021-09-24T16:09:09.074813Z"
},
{
"id": 2,
"status": "True",
"inputvalues": "[4, 3, 2, 1]",
"timestamp": "2021-09-24T16:08:09.207566Z"
},
{
"id": 1,
"status": "False",
"inputvalues": "[8, 6, 6, 5, 5, 4, 4]",
"timestamp": "2021-09-24T15:51:32.396178Z"
}
]